# Absolute positioned element position not relative to parent container in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I've got a simple form where I'm trying to align two fields horizontally that will take money inputs.  I want to label the inputs with a $ (that should not be editable) so that people know to put in money. I ended up doing this with an absolutely positioned span element.  The jsfiddle is at http://jsfiddle.net/7tCfe/2/.

Everything works fine in Internet Explorer and Firefox, but in Chrome the currency label for the second money input gets positioned all the way to the left instead of inside the second input. In the jsfiddle, the second symbol is on top of the symbol for the first money field.

How do I get Chrome to position an element absolutely relative to a parent element? I've tried messing with the `.two-column` class and changing it's display and position but it just ends up breaking the rest of the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `one-column` class to the second `<div>` as well, and add `clear: both;` to the following `<div>`'s style. You can do this with [an inline `style` attribute](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/3gXpL/) *(meh)* or by [using an additional class](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/NczJb/), or [with the following CSS rule](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/gw5Cj/):

```
.one-column + div:not(.one-column) {
    clear: both;
}
```

However, [`:not` does not work in IE <9](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t30), so (if you care about IE) you probably want to [use a different selector](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/tm6se/), such as

```
.one-column + .one-column + div {
    clear: both;
}
```

Yes, IE's CSS 3 selector support is abysmal.

Comment: This is close, but unfortunately this form is contained in another <div> that is already floated left.  When I do the `clear: both` that field gets repositioned below the right floated element.  Skipping the 'clear: both' but adding the one-column class to the second div leaves me with the problem I started with.

Comment: I updated the JSFiddle to show the problem better in context.

Comment: *why??* why wouldn't you just suggest adding a rule for `.two-column` instead of this selector soup?